# Directory not creating using mkdir() or mkdirs()

Tags: java, android

Below is my code for MainActivity.java.**The error according to toasts is in creating directory.**

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode,int resultcode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestcode,resultcode,data);
     if (requestcode == TAKE_PICTURE) 
        {
        if(resultcode== Activity.RESULT_OK){

            ImageView imageHolder = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_camera);
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");

            String partFilename = currentDateFormat();
            storeCameraPhotoInSDCard(bitmap, partFilename);

            // display the image from SD Card to ImageView Control
            String storeFilename = "photo_" + partFilename + ".jpg";
            Bitmap mBitmap = getImageFileFromSDCard(storeFilename);
            imageHolder.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        }
        }
 }

  private String currentDateFormat(){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss");
        String  currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date(0));
        return currentTimeStamp;
    }
  /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
  public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
      String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
      if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WriteMode ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
      }
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WriteMode OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return false;
  }

  /* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
  public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
      String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
      if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
          Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Mounted or ReadMode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
      }
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no-Mounted or no-ReadMode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return false;
  }

    private void storeCameraPhotoInSDCard(Bitmap bitmap, String currentDate){
        boolean isAvailable=isExternalStorageWritable();
        if(isAvailable){
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90, bytes);
            String imgUri =  "photo_" + currentDate + ".jpg";
            File appDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"CountDotsAppImages");
            boolean success = appDirectory.mkdirs();
            if (success) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed - Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"CountDotsAppImages/"+imgUri);
            FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }

    private Bitmap getImageFileFromSDCard(String filename){
     File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/", "CountDotsAppImages");

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        File imageFile = new File(storageDir.getPath()+File.separator + filename);
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, imageFile.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` permission is added

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.countdots"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Toasts Output : 
   Mounted or ReadMode 
   WriteMode ON  
   Directory Does Not Exist, Create It 
   **Failed -Error**    //Error in creating directory mkdir

I tried using both mkdir() and mkdirs()

Comment: `void storeCameraPhotoInSDCard`. Make that `boolean storeCameraPhotoInSDCard` and add `return false;` directly after mkdirs fails. You are blindly continuing with your code to use a directory even if that does not exist.

Comment: `isExternalStorageReadable();
            isExternalStorageWritable();`. Yu are calling both functions but do nothing with the result. You should call them one by one and directly return false if they return false as it makes no sense to continue with the code than.

Comment: `Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
                Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`. Remove all those lines and replace by one toast using outputFile directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Figured it out.**
As, I was compiling with Android 6.0. It requires user to grant permission.
So,following code should be inserted and checked if user grants app permission or not.Then if user grants permission to read and write manifest will be updated and volia !!!

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        1);
            } else {
                //do something
            }
        } else {
                //do something
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
            try{
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90, bytes);
                imgUri =  "photo_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                File appDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"CountDotsAppImages");
                appDirectory.mkdirs();
                File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"CountDotsAppImages/"+imgUri);
                FileOutputStream fo;
                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: boolean success = appDirectory.mkdirs();
                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed - Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                 It shows Falied -Error.

Comment: have you checked if the directory exists because It fails if the directory already exists ?

Comment: yes I checked, no directory name CountDotsAppImages is created in /storage/emulated/0/.

Answer (score 0):

For adding directory you can use this method.

```
isAvailable=ExternalStorageChecker.isExternalStorageWritable();
        if(isAvailable){

            dir = new File(myContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), newAlbumDir.getText().toString().trim());
            if(!dir.mkdirs()){
                Log.e("++++++","Directoy Already Exist");
                Log.e("External Directory Path","++++"+dir.getAbsolutePath());

            }
            else{
                Log.e("++++","Directory Created");
                Toast.makeText(myContext,"File Created on External",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Externa Directory Path","++++"+dir.getAbsolutePath());
              }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(myContext,"File Created on Internal",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.e("Internal Directory Path","++++"+myContext.getFilesDir().getPath());
            dir=new File(myContext.getFilesDir(),newAlbumDir.getText().toString());

        }
```

After it created the directory(dir) you can use to create the File.